# How to open youtube in webview in ios7

Tags: ios, ios7, uiwebview

I'm trying load youtube in `UIWebview` in *iOS7* device using embedded string,its not loading.
But in simulator and below *iOS7* devices are working  good.
Please suggest me how to solve this.
I'm using like below,

```
 NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = yes, width = 320\"/></head><body style=\"background:#00;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"><div><object width=\"320\" height=\"180\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/%@&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\"></param><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param><embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/%@&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\"type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"768\" height='%0.0f'></embed></object></div></body></html>", strurl, strurl,webview.frame.size.height];
```